# executing slow process with popen()

Tags: c, popen, nmap

I'm creating a simple network scanning function using nmap and C. I want to use popen() to execute nmap, but nmap takes close to 30 seconds to complete because I'm scanning a wide range of IPs.

So, is there a way to check when the command has finished executing? I don't want my C code to hang at the system call, instead I would like to just check a flag or something in a loop that will know when popen/nmap has finished so other parts of my C program don't come to an halt. Is this possible??

Thanks!

Comment: Of course it's possible. What have you attempted so far? Have you tried [`fork(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html)? directly?

Comment: The `SIGCHLD` signal is sent to the parent of a child process when it exits.

Comment: @iharob I have not attempted fork, but my mind was already leaning towards pthreads, so I think I'll take that route. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of 2 direct ways to do it

1. You could `fork()` directly and then establish a way to communicate the two processes, this would be very difficult because IPC is not an easy matter.
2. You could create a new thread with `pthread_create()` and call `popen()` there, it would be a lot easier and you could share data between threads by using an appropriate locking mechanism to prevent race conditions.

Comment: The right answer is 3. `posix_spawn()/posix_spawnp()`.

Comment: @iharob I am running into some roadblocks as I am new to even the most simple threading. My main question right now is, How would I know my thread has finished executing so I know when it's ok to mess with popen's output?

Comment: This is a very broad question, if you need anymore help please send me an e-mail to iharob@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You can either use multi processing with [fork](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) (hardmode)

Or you can use multithreading using [pthread](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) (easymode)

Either one allows you to do 2 things at once. Multiprocessing is hard because you must worry about innerproccess communications (pipes) and the 2 tasks you're trying to do can not share memory.

Multithreading is a much more easy because all you need is to include the libraries (`-lpthread`) and then specify what function is on the seperate thread.

Comment: Given that the question is about executing an external program, the relative difficulties of using threads and processes are somewhat different than this answer suggests.